# Duvida sobre JPQL

Tags: sql, jsf, hibernate, mysqli, cdi

sinceramente tenho uma certa dificuldade com BD, e preciso de uma JPQL que retorne apenas um registro. Tenho uma entidade Preço e uma entidade Produto. Preciso trazer o ultimo preço cadastrado pelo usuário. Coloquei uma data e um ID, imagino que poderia ser o ultimo ID ou mesmo a ultima data cadastrada (tenho uma dataLancamento). Mas como faço isso ? Meu BD é o MYSQL e estou usando Hibernate,CDI e JSF.

Tabela preço:

id | dataLancamento | valor | .... produto_id |

```
public Preco findByIdProdutoUltimoPreco(Integer produtoId) {
    TypedQuery<Preco> query = em.createQuery(
            "????",
            Preco.class);
    query.setParameter("pid", produtoId);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para saber o ultimo registro baseado no `id` e no parâmetro, bastaria usar:

- `ORDER BY id DESC`: ordenar registros em ordem decrescente baseado no `id`
- `LIMIT 1`: limitar para que retorne somente 1 registro:
- `WHERE produto_id = :pid`: retornar registros com o produto específico

Então sua query ficaria desta forma:

```
SELECT id, dataLancamento, valor, produto_id FROM nameTable 
WHERE produto_id = produtoId ORDER BY id DESC limit 1
```

Adaptando no seu código ficaria desta forma:

```
public Preco findByIdProdutoUltimoPreco(Integer produtoId) {
    TypedQuery<Preco> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT id, dataLancamento, valor, produto_id FROM nameTable 
    WHERE produto_id = :pid ORDER BY id DESC limit 1",
            Preco.class);
    query.setParameter("pid", produtoId);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```